# two way binding failed on expression value and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The expression value only update on data load and then it won't be changed anymore.

Though the slider's value has changed and trigger the `filterPrices` function

I saw the value was changed on the console but the view still kept the same value.

[image: inline]

## controller

it will trigger on load and when the value of sliderbar changes.

```
$scope.filterPrices = function(chart){
  # select the cheapest flight here
  console.log(target_flight.y)
  chart.target_flight = target_flight;
}
```

## directive (sliderbar)

Trigger the controller function `filterPrices`

```
    link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
        $(element).ionRangeSlider({
                onChange: function(slider) {
                    var _this = this;
                    updateFlighSeries(slider, scope[_this.chartConfig].series)
                    angular.forEach(scope.chart_names, function(chart_cfg_name){
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.filterPrices(scope[chart_cfg_name])
                          });
                      }, 2000);
                    }, scope)
                    scope.$apply();
                }
        });
```

## HTML

```
  <li class="col-4 color7">
    <span>> departure flight</span>
    {{ departChartConfig.target_flight.y }}
  </li>
  <li class="col-4 color7">
    <span>> return flight</span>
    {{ returnChartConfig.target_flight.y }}
  </li>
```

## updated (still not working)

```
  onChange: function(slider) {
                var _this = this;
                updateFlighSeries(slider, scope[_this.chartConfig].series)
                angular.forEach(scope.chart_names, function(chart_cfg_name){
                  $timeout(function () {
                      // scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.filterPrices(scope[chart_cfg_name])
                      // });
                  }, 200);
                }, scope)

            }
```

Comment: Try to use $timeout instead of setTimeout and remove $apply. This will allow angular to manage the $digest cycle. But I'm not sure why  scope.$apply not working.

Comment: updated (still not working)

Comment: please, create plunker which reproduces the problem...

Comment: Try to show us an example. Look, your code simple emulation works - http://codepen.io/vshulyk/pen/PNbrbN?editors=1011.